# Haskell, input arguments, return type

Tags: haskell

For this piece of haskell code:

```
isIn :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [a] -> Bool
needle `isIn` haystack = any (needle `isPrefixOf`) (tails haystack)
```

This is a function definition I believe. How do I understand what the input arguments are and what the return type is?

For example: what is `(Eq a)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Eq` is what's called a [typeclass](http://learnyouahaskell.com/types-and-typeclasses). It declares a few functions, in this case `==` and friends, and we can make instances of that typeclass which provide definitions for `==` and others.

This means that when we have something that's an instance of the `Eq` typeclass, we know we can use `==` on it.

The trick here is that in our function, we need to have types which make it possible to check that they're equal. If we just had `[a] -> [a] -> Bool` then we'd be in trouble because we'd have just promised that our implementation works on things without an `==` operator which it doesn't.

Because of this we use the `=>` which adds context to our function definition. It says something like "This will work for any `a` *as long as* `a` is an instance of the `Eq` typeclass". That way, we can use `==` safely and know that all our argument types will implement it appropriately.

**Quick Illustration**

This is an error:

```
doIfEqual :: a -> a -> (a -> a -> [a])
doIfEqual a b f = if a==b then f a b else []
```

but this works because we specify `a` is an instance of `Eq`

```
doIfEqual (Eq a) => a -> a -> (a -> a -> [a])
doIfEqual a b f = if a==b then f a b else []
```

Comment: Thank you jozefg, This is a informative and clear explanation. Thanks!